# Django advanced LIKE filtering

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, sql-like

So I'm trying to find a nice way to execute an advanced filter using the LIKE statement in Django.

Let's say I have the following records in a table called `elements`:

```
id = 1, name = 'group[1].car[8]'
id = 2, name = 'group[1].car[9]'
id = 3, name = 'group[1].truck[1]'
id = 4, name = 'group[1].car[10]'
id = 4, name = 'group[1].carVendor[1]'
```

I would like to select all elements that look like group[x].car[y].

To query this in SQL I would do:

```
SELECT * FROM elements WHERE name LIKE 'group[%].car[%]'
```

Now, by reading the Django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups), I see that the only pre-built LIKE statements are the following:

1. contains: `name LIKE '%something%'`
2. startswith: `name LIKE 'something%'`
3. endswith: `name LIKE '%something'`

So the one I need is missing:

4. plain like: `name LIKE 'group[%].car[%]'`

I'm also using Django Rest Framework to write up my API endpoints and also here we find the possibility to use:

1. contains: `name__contains = something`
2. startswith: `name__startswith = something`
3. endswith: `name__endswith = something`

So also here, the one I need is missing:

4. plain like: `name__like 'group[%].car[%]'`

Of course I know I can write a raw sql query through Django using the `raw()` method, but I would like to use this option if no better solution comes up, because:

1. I need to make sure my customization is safe
2. I need to extends the customization to DRF

Can anybody think of a way to help me out with this in a way to go with the flow with both Django and Django Rest Framework?

Comment: you should read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#regex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [*regular expression (regex)* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) for this, with the [**`__iregex`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iregex):

```
Elements.objects.filter(name__iregex=r'^group\[.*\].car\[.*\]$')
```

if between the square brackets, only *digits* are allowed, we can make it more specific with:

```
# only digits between the square brackets
Elements.objects.filter(name__iregex=r'^group\[\d*\].car\[\d*\]$')
```

Since some the specifications are a bit "complex" it is better to first *test* your regex, for example with [**regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/n9BDbG/2) you can look what `name`s will be matched, and which will not.